# Vue.js Modal component shows up in component list, but the modal doesn't actually show

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to display an items details on click of a button, I have the data going to the modal properly, but I can't seem to get the modal to actually show up. I've tried different implementations of a modal in the template, and the closes I've gotten was having a grey screen show up on the button press. I'm at a loss of what to do at this point because every tutorial I try on modals doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using VUE CLI version 2

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <Navbar />
    <Ordertiles @childToParent="onClickChild"/>
    <div v-if="showModal">
    <Modal @close="toggleModal" :header="item.header" :text="item.text" :image="item.img"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue'
import Ordertiles from '@/components/Ordertiles.vue'
import Modal from '@/components/Modal.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Ordertiles,
    Modal
  },
  data() {
    return {
      item: '',
      showModal: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleModal() {
      this.showModal = !this.showModal
    },
    onClickChild(item) {
      this.item = item
      console.log(this.item)
      this.toggleModal()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Modal.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="modal__title">Direction</div>
      <p>{{header}}</p>
      <img v-bind:src="image"> 
      <p> {{text}} </p>
      <button class="mt-3 border-b border-teal font-semibold">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: ['header', 'text', "image"],
  methods: {
    close () {
      this.$emit('close')
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
  .modal {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  }
</style>
```

[Before Clicking the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyPH4.png)
[After button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVb3h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a modal example that actually works for me

Modal.vue

```
<template>
  <transition name="modal">
        <div class="modal-mask">
          <div class="modal-wrapper">
            <div class="modal-container">

              <div class="modal-header">
                <slot name="header">
                  default header
                </slot>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-body">
                <slot name="body">
                  default body
                </slot>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <slot name="footer">
                  default footer
                  <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                    OK
                  </button>
                </slot>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: ['header', 'text', "image"],
  methods: {
    close () {
      this.$emit('close')
    }
  },
  components: {
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
  .modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: table;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.modal-header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #42b983;
}

.modal-body {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.modal-default-button {
  float: right;
}

.modal-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-enter .modal-container,
.modal-leave-active .modal-container {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use other npm  modal packages like vue-modality .I strong vouch for this package.Its easy to use and understand. This will save you a great amount of time as you dont re-invent the wheel.Check out this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-modality

Comment: I just tried using Vue-modality, and I still have the same issue happening. The modal component shows up, but it doesn't display anything. When I hover over the modal component in dev-tools it doesn't display the location of the modal either.

Comment: With vue-modality, are you using a function that calls the show methods of the modal?

Comment: I'm not exactly where I wish to put the method that shows the modal, Currently, each button/item that I want to have is in an orderTiles component. I send the data back to Home.vue and then have the div with if toggle modal. I can't really find a good spot to put this.$refs.myRef.open(). The issue is most likely me just being dumb.

Comment: I ended up finding a solution to my modal problems, thanks for the help though!